# What is the best practice for API based registration from an Android app to Laravel

Tags: android, laravel, api

I wonder how can I make an application for android that user can register in Laravel API based application.
One of the most important thing in laravel form processing is the CSFR token that (I think) every POST request needs.
I know that there is a token based authentication that can make the integration safe, but as the very first step, how can I make it safe for registration that only users using my app could register.

Comment: See this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Answer (score 0):

also you can use "jwt package" for laravel that give you a token. then you can use from that in per request.also you can deactive csfr token.

Answer (score 0):

1. add passport package to your project ,see this for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport
2. create password grant client
3. create new user with token
4. use retrofit or another package to call Laravel api

   ```
    /* prepare httpClient */
   httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
       @Override
       public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
           Request orginal = chain.request();
           Request.Builder builder = orginal.newBuilder();
           builder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
           if (tools.isAuthorized()) {
               builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tools.getAccessToken());
           }
           builder.method(orginal.method(), orginal.body());
           Request build = builder.build();
           return chain.proceed(build);
       }});
   ```

   5- call api and get response then save user token.